# Most of my experience section disappeared

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

A few months ago, I signed up for a Careers account after getting an invite.  I filled out a good chunk of information within a day or two, most notably adding two Experience points with long descriptions.

I know that the data was saved, as I went back later and added more information - and then checked back again within a week to make sure my account information was still there, chillin' (it was).

However, when I log in 2 months later, I only see one item under "experience" - and no information in the "responsibilities" edit that I had filled out before!

Where did my first experience item go, and where did my book of a description disappear to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that TehStrike.  I've restored your profile to its former glory.  Let me know if anything else is out of place.

Comment: Ah, much thanks!  What caused this to happen?  Is there some sort of regular incantation I can perform over my profile that would prevent such things in the future?

Comment: @TehStrike: Some people have a problem they think they can solve with regular incantations.  Now they have two problems :)  

Everything should be OK going forward, you just had two accounts that needed to be merged.